# In PHP use 'img src' as part of data attribute

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a table using both Bootstrap and PHP, which makes use of Popovers. I would ideally like my popover to include a JPG but as I am already using echo to create my html table I am unsure how to incorporate it. I have tried to include the usual 'img src' as shown below but it's just printing out the code.

```
echo "<td colspan='$newlength' id='example' rel='popover' data-content='<img src='imagetouse.jpg' /> This is my content.' data-title=' This is my Title'>$name . $time2</td>";
```

The above code terminates the  tags after the image src. I am unable to use "" around my image because they surround the whole  tags for the echo therefore again terminating the code.

Having attempted nietonfir's suggestion:

```
echo '<td colspan="' . $newlength . '" id="example" rel="popover" data-content="<img src=\'imagetouse.jpg\' /> This is my content." data-title="This is my Title">' . $name . $time2 . '</td>';
```

The content of my popover now reads as opposed to displaying the image:

```
<img src='imagetouse.jpg' /> This is my content.
```

Comment: Because you need to set `data-html="true"` as well (as mentioned multiple times in my answer)! Else the content is added via `text()` where everything gets escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one I think that you should move the image to the content attribute. And I couldn't find a description to "original-title", so I assume you just meant title. According to the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) you can insert HTML into the popover by setting an attribute. See this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ISuqINi/2) for a demo.

```
<div id="foo" data-html="true" data-content="<img src='http://placehold.it/200x100' /> Content" data-title="Title!">Click</div>
```

[edit]
Concerning your wrong output statement, the following snippet might fix your issue (please be aware that I didn't incorporate the necessary `data-html="true"` change for the popover to work):

```
echo '<td colspan="' . $newlength . '" id="example" rel="popover" data-content="<img src=\'imagetouse.jpg\' /> This is my content." data-title="This is my Title">' . $name . $time2 . '</td>';
```

Imho you should always terminate your strings and concatenate them. In the case of DOM output I'd even terminate the parser and output the variables individually like

```
?>
<td colspan="<?php echo $newlength; ?>" id="example" rel="popover" data-content="<img src='imagetouse.jpg' /> This is my content." data-title="This is my Title"><?php echo $name . $time2;?></td>
```

This way it is easier to spot mistakes for one. And on the other side your editor can highlight your code as what it is: HTML.

Comment: I see what you're saying regarding including the image in the content - however it's still not working. I think the problem lies in the fact that my whole <td> statement is being echoed and them wrapped in " " - the <> and  '' of the img tag result in html being printed!

Comment: There is no erroneous output as such, just problems with the mark up terminating early meaning that markup is printing in cells. I've tried to include a better problem description in the question.

Comment: @Gwenji Updated my answer accordingly.